# Excel Compute LTV Lifetime Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a simple spreadsheet of transactions that contains ONE common field: email address.

How could I create a pivot table or something that has a Total of all the transactions under an email address?
(some contacts have 3 or 4 transactions all with the same email address.)

the two columns are:

email | price

I'd like the output to be email | Total (sum of all transactions under a given email)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a pivot table and select your range.
Add email to rows and add price to values.
[image]